# Importing value from MySQL into JavaScript as variable

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm trying to make a Database for a film distrubution. i got 3 tables: client, movies and borrowing and I want to get the price value from the movies table and multiply it with the days rented to get the final costs for borrowing it for x days. How can i import the value of the price and calculate with it?
i got:

```
app.get("/ausleihen/get/kosten", function(req,res) {
const moviename= req.body.filmName;
const sqlGet = "SELECT costs FROM movies WHERE moviename=  ?;"
connection.query(sqlGet, moviename, (err, result) =>{
    varCosts=result;
});
```

});

app.post("/ausleihen/insert", (req, res)=>{

```
const prename= req.body.prename;
const lastname= req.body.lastname;
const moeviename= req.body.moeviename;
const begin= req.body.begin;
const end= req.body.end;
const begin1= new Date(req.body.begin).valueOf();
const end1= new Date(req.body.end).valueOf();

const diff = Math.abs(end1-begin1);
const diffDays = Math.ceil(diff / (1000*60*60*24));
const costs= diffDays;



const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO ausleihen (moviename, prename, lastname, begin, end, costs) VALUES (?,?,?,moviename, prename, lastname, begin, end, costs], (err, result)=>{
    console.log(err);
})
```

});

Comment: Why do you have a app.get() inside an app.post() ?

Comment: whoops messed up when copy pasting. its over the app.post normally

Comment: just corrected it

Comment: In which request you want to do that ?

Comment: ive tried getting it from the app.get but varCosts stays undifined.
basically i want the return of the SELECT request on the varCosts

Comment: it should be var costs then ?

Comment: yeah. i got th table movies with the cost for every individual movie and want to mupliply it with the days to get the total costs for the customer

Comment: But a customer could have rented a same film multiple times, what data you are going to use ? a borrowing_id of some sort ? Or you want to add up all borrowings of that customer for that film ? You could make a join in your request : `SELECT movies.costs,ausleihen.costs FROM movies WHERE movies.moviename =  ? JOIN ausleihen ON ausleihen.moviename = movies.moviename AND ausleihen.customer_id = ?`

Comment: yeah i got a id that auto increments for that but for now i just want to get the costs

Comment: i know its simple but i dont need to combine everthing toghether...yet

Comment: So it's for a single borrowing ? or the most recent borrowing of that film ?

Comment: yeah exactly. a new one thats why its insert into the table

Comment: then you  could use something like that : `SELECT movies.costs,ausleihen.costs FROM movies WHERE movies.moviename =  ? JOIN ausleihen ON ausleihen.moviename = movies.moviename AND ausleihen.customer_id = ? LIMIT 1` you will get the last borrowing (order by id by default)

Comment: and how do i get the value to multiply it with the amount of days and insert it as total costs in the table?

Comment: Well you have the value i don't understand, it's the result of the request you made, you get the cost from the film and the number of days from the borrowing in one request using a join, then you just have to multiply it and you have your result

Comment: Do you mean the varCosts variable? its supposed to take the return value from the get statement but it stays undefined

Comment: it's supposd to be `var costs` not `varCosts` i think

Comment: no its called 'varCosts' because its the variable costs for each movie. declared it as 'var varCosts'

Comment: just fixed it with another query inside the app.post